# SDWebImage for Swift, Blur effect is it possible?

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage for Swift in my project and I am trying to add a Blur effect to an image following the advance usage example found [here](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/wiki/Advanced-Usage).

More specifically I am trying to declare a `SDImageBlurTransformer` but when I start typing the option doesn't come up.

[image: b]

Is an image blur effect possible using SDWebImage package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Podfile refers to version 5.0 of the project and run a `pod update`.  I have the code completion coming up properly on a new project using version 5.0 of SDWebImage.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode with code completion for SDImageBlurTransformer]

Here's my `Podfile` for reference:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'BlurImage' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'

end
```